# SPSS grouping data

Tags: spss

I have some data in SPSS which has number of columns including “gender”.

I want to find the mean of a column let’s say A, but between males and females in gender column.

Can someone guide as how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the mean in the output window you can do this:

```
means A by Gender.
```

If you want to get this and other statistics in a new datast for further analysis you can use aggregation. For example:

```
dataset declare aggByGender.
aggregate out=aggByGender /break gender /MeanA=mean(A) /maxA maxB=max(A b).
dataset activate aggByGender.
```